# What approach should I use to do client side filtering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I am making the front end of a asp.net mvc3 web application. A controller action sends a database driven list to a view model which then populates a series of divs. I have a filtering section above the div list. I am not sure which approach to take to implement the filter. I have considered rolling my own (I always keep this option on the table), using jQuery's .filter(), or finding some JavaScript functionality to use.

What is the standard way to filter client side with JavaScript (or a js derived library)?

*EDIT*

For gdoron's lack of context:

js

```
var gdoronArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
 gdoronArray.push("text" + i + " " + (i*10));
}
```

Is there a standard library to pull only the items in gdoronArray which contain "ext5" or is this just a roll your own situation?

Comment: I can't really understand the question.

Comment: @gdoron - What do you know about filtering?

Comment: What do you know about object-oriented? what a specific question...

Comment: you need click events and then filter methods based on the filter section clicked or manipulated. This is not a very good question for SO, it is too broad and is asking for an opinion.

Comment: @KevinB - The context given was filtering, not how to handle the user interaction.

Comment: @gdoron - Context must not be a strong point for you.

Comment: What type of filtering are you doing? what are you filtering? What does the "filter" contain?

Comment: Generally when you are filtering a table, you do it with a textbox that as you type, it filters the table down to only results that match the text in the filter. This can be done with a keyup event on the text input that then searches the table for irrelevant rows and hides them.

Comment: Filters may also contain select boxes, list boxes, radio buttons, checkboxes, etc. There is no standard to filtering data.

Comment: @KevinB - I am just curious, as the context tags would have implied, about the javascript aspect here. Not user interaction or UX. Please see my edit.

Comment: What's wrong with `filter()`?

Comment: @KevinB - No standards? Just have at it?

Comment: @TravisJ Look at it this way. There are numerous things that you can possibly filter. Arrays you can use the Array.filter method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Please, talk about the question in the comments, for discussion / debate you can go to the [CHAT](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) Try be objective so the comments may help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gdoronArray.filter( function(v){
    return !!~v.indexOf("ext5");
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Btw, it'd be nice to precise this solution is not cross-browser :)

Comment: A fix to the cross-browser issue would be to include the code from the compatibility section of this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @KevinB - Will that fix make IE8 comply with `.filter`? IE8 is a huge part of the market and cannot be overlooked. At the bottom of that link, it states that only IE9+ is compatible.

Comment: @TravisJ Yes the code is plain javascript and works in IE6-8. It just isn't included natively out of the box in those browsers. But it doesn't do anything magic so it can be done with the code that is listed in the link.